# Copy Char to char*

Tags: c, string, pointers, copy, char

I have a question for C programming.
I have a loop where I generate at each iteration a new char. Each generated char I want to append to a string (char *)
This is my code:

```
char *string[20];
string[0]=0;

for (p = 0; p < length(message) - 1; p = p + 2)
{
...
char cc="";
cc = (char) strtol(pp, pp, 16);
char *tt[2];
tt[0]="";
*tt=(char *)cc;
strcat(string,cc);
}
```

I know that strcat uses char*. So I tried to copy the content of the char i wanna append to a new pointer.
I have probably done sth wrong...i'm not very experienced.
Thank you

Reason for strtol:
I have a char* msg, that holds a hexa number. I want to process that hexa number but when I try to do for instance shifting (<<16) is shifts 16 bits (multiplies by 2^16 ) the decimal ascii value of the hexa character, instead of shifting the character itself.
So, I converted the hexa number to a character, so that when I try to do shifting it will shift the correct value. I know it' wierd.
Cann you help me come up with sth better?

```
unsigned char *octets0"3F214365876616AB15387D5D59";
crc ^= ((*octets++) << 16);
```

Comment: A `char*` is not a string. It is a pointer to a string. **pointers and arrays are not the same** (read section 6 of [the c-faq](http://c-faq.com/)). A string is an array of char with some definite length.

Answer (score 1):

Several issues.

First problem is that you've created an array of `char` pointers, not a `char` array. You want:

```
char string[20];
```

In C, an array implicitly "degrades" into a pointer to its first element, so if you pass just `string` it's a `char*` ( `string == &string[0]` )

From there ... no idea what `pp` is, but `strtol()` returns a `long int` which you're trying to assign to a `char` - that's not going to work the way you think. You're short about 7 bytes.

(Edited to define "work" as in "Not what you think")

Comment: Assigning a `long int` to a `char` should work, yes. Simple conversion between integral types. Your compiler may (correctly) warn that you might “lose precision” or whatever words they use, and the call should be `strtol(pp, &pp, 16)` and is probably not what was intended etc., though.

Comment: Ok, how about "That's not going to work the way you think it does" ? :)

Comment: I have a char* msg, that holds a hexa number.
I want to process that hexa number but when I try to do for instaance shifting (<<16) is shifts 16 bits(multiplies by 2^16 ) the decimal ascii value of the hexa character, instead of shifting the character itself

Comment: @Brian: A lot of things seem not to work the way he expected, but I don't know if this individual assignment is among them. :-) If I had to guess, I'd say the `strtol` call was meant to convert two hex chars into a numerical representation of a character, as in decoding `48656c6c6f20576f726c6421` – it won't do that, because `strtol` doesn't want to be told where to stop among other problems, but the appending to a string and the `p = p+2` part look suspiciously like it. Obviously, that's just guesswork, though.

Comment: @DDC: You could open a new question or edit the question already posted to say what you actually want to achieve. With expected input/output pairs, if possible.

Comment: @DDC - if you post actual code that is able to be compiled and ask for specific help .. we might be able to offer suggestions. As it is, the code snippit you post makes little sense and all we can do is point out the glaring mistakes and guess at the rest.

Comment: Ok, i will open a new question. Thx for the help

Comment: Here is the updated question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316901/crc24q-implementation

Answer (score 0):

Try not to cast between `char*` and `char` – it does not do anything useful and your compiler should not let you do that, anyway. If you really want to use `strcat`, that should be

```
char cc; // no ="" here!
...
tt[0] = cc;
strcat(string, tt)
```

But it would be much easier to just do what cnicutar posted above (I was going to type something like that here, too).